# Selected value of DataGridViewComboBoxCell

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, gridview

I am using the following code to bind a combo box column in gridview

```
DataGridViewComboBoxCell dgBatch = (DataGridViewComboBoxCell)grvProduct.Rows[pRowIndex].Cells[pComboColName];
            DataTable dtBatch = new DataTable();
            dtBatch = iExportSalesOrder.SelectProductDetails(pack_detl_ID);
            dgBatch.DataSource = dtBatch;
            dgBatch.ValueMember = "qty";
            dgBatch.DisplayMember = "sBatch_No";
```

I want to set a `particular item as selected` in this combo box based on some value. How can i set a `selectedvalue in DataGridViewComboBoxCell` .?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set `dgBatch.Value = "selectedValue"` it should work.

Answer (score 0):

```
dgBatch[Column.Name, Row.Name].Value = value;
```